# Replacing Null Values in HashMap with Empty String Java

Tags: java

Im trying to replace all the null values in my HashMap with an empty String i.e. `example=null` to `example=`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Object> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put("0", {"a":"1","b":null,"c":"someString"});
            put("1", {"a":"2","b":"someString","c":null});
        }
    }
    mapOfObjects = new ReplaceNullValues().replaceHashMapNullValues(mapOfObjects);
}

public Map <String, Object> replaceHashMapNullValues(Map <String, Object> replaceNullValues) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(int index = 0; index < replaceNullValues.size(); index++){
        JSONObject objects = (JSONObject) replaceNullValues.get(Integer.toString(index));
        JSONArray keys = objects.names();

        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length (); ++i){
           String key = keys.getString (i); 
           String value = objects.getString (key);

           if(value.equals("null")){
               value = "";
           }               
           map.put(key, value);            
        }           
        replaceNullValues.put(Integer.toString(index), map);        
    }       
    return replaceNullValues;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
{0={a=2,b=someString,c=},1={a=2,b=someString,c=}}
```

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
{0={a=1,b=,c=someString},1={a=2,b=someString,c=}}
```

Comment: Try value == null.  null and "null" are not the same. And since you're checking for null, you don't need to use equals.

Comment: is this (pure)  Java? I can't see what `{"a":"1","b":null,"c":"someString"}` means in the subclass of `HashMap`

Comment: You keep using the same instance of `map` in your iterations. Try creating a new instance in the outer loop

Comment: The condition should be value == null. "null" evaluates to string literal 'null'

Comment: @WJS, @MRTJ that's not the issue because ```String value = objects.getString (key)``` is converting null to "null". So ```value == null``` will not work. I'm able to get the desired replacement i.e. ```{0={a=2,b=someString,c=},1={a=2,b=someString,c=}}``` but keys 0 and 1 are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I firgured it out. Thank you @iluxa for pointing me in the right direction. I was using the same instance of map in my iterations. I created a new instance in the outer loop and it solved my problem.

Solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Object> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put("0", {"a":"1","b":null,"c":"someString"});
            put("1", {"a":"2","b":"someString","c":null});
        }
    }
    mapOfObjects = new ReplaceNullValues().replaceHashMapNullValues(mapOfObjects);
}

public Map <String, Object> replaceHashMapNullValues(Map <String, Object> replaceNullValues) throws JSONException {
    for(int index = 0; index < replaceNullValues.size(); index++){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();            

        JSONObject objects = (JSONObject) replaceNullValues.get(Integer.toString(index));
        JSONArray keys = objects.names();

        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length (); ++i){
           String key = keys.getString (i); 
           String value = objects.getString (key);

           if(value.equals("null")){
               value = "";
           }               
           map.put(key, value);            
        }           
        replaceNullValues.replace(Integer.toString(index), newMap);     
    }       
    return replaceNullValues;       
}
```

Comment: also not (pure) Java - how can a `Map` be assigned to a `HashMap` without casting?